# Express-Validator v4 minimalistic example always return error

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I can't get this very basic piece of code to work in the new version. Here is my code

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const validator = require("express-validator");
const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator/check");

    const app = express(); 
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(validator());

    app.post('/',
             [ check("email").isEmail() ],
             (req, resp) => { 
                const errors = validationResult(req);
                resp.send(errors.mapped()); });
    
app.listen(3000, () => { console.log('listening on port 3000'); });
```

I send a post request with body containing :

```
{ "email": "ha@gmail.com" }
```

The Response is ALWAYS an error  even if the email I give is perfectly correct

```
{ "email": { "location": "body", "param": "email", "msg": "Invalid value" } }
```

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `req.body.email` is always `undefined`, you have to tell `body-parser` middleware to parse incoming request bodies into object by adding this line:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

One other thing, always use `errors.isEmpty()` to check whether the validation  contains errors or not:

```
app.post('/send', [ check("email").isEmail() ], (req, resp) => { 

    console.log(req.body);

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return resp.send(errors.mapped()); 
    }

    resp.send('no errors');

});
```